# need an efficient method to count datasets by name in an hdf5 file with Python

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have a dataset.h5 file that contains within it "files" that are numbered using the following format:

/frame_0000_000

Where the first four numbers correspond to a person's ID, and the second three numbers correspond to the image ID. Essentially it looks like this in the file (but with thousands of entries)

```
/frame_0000_000
/frame_0000_001
/frame_0000_002
/frame_0001_000
/frame_0001_001
```

I am trying to make an array with each person as an element (based on the files) and trying to make a second array which has the number of images per person. i.e person 0 has 3 images.

Below is what I have attempted, but I can't help but think there must be a better way (more efficient) which is why I am asking. I've searched around quite a bit and would appreciate guidance. Especially because my code doesn't recognise the number of images for the last person.

I'm still learning to code and would highly appreciate your help here. Thank you.

P.S I cannot share the dataset.

```
import h5py
test = h5py.File(filename, 'r')

uniquesubjects = []
uniqueframes = []

count = 0
for (idx,st) in enumerate (test,1):
    splitter = st.split('_')    
    if (splitter[0]=='frame'):
        subject = splitter[1]
        if subject not in uniquesubjects and subject =='0000':
            uniquesubjects.append(subject)
        if subject not in uniquesubjects:
            uniquesubjects.append(subject)
            uniqueframes.append(count)
            count = 0
        if subject in uniquesubjects:
            count = count+1
print(uniqueframes)
print(uniquesubjects)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a dictionary would be a better data structure for your purposes.
This example creates a HDF5 file to mimic your file structure. It has a random number of frames for each subject (between 1-4).
After creating the file, it the loops on the root level names (assumes all are datasets), and creates a dictionary where the key the subject id and the value is the count.
Once it exits the loop, it creates 3 different NumPy arrays from the dictionary: 1) `arr0` has both subject and count, 2) `arr1` only has the subject and 3) `arr2` only has the count.
Everything is printed so you can see what's going on.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
  
arr = np.random.rand(10,2,2)
with h5py.File('SO_67702838.h5','w') as h5f:
    for pid in range(0,220,20):
        nframes = np.random.randint(1,5)
        for nfr in range(nframes):
            h5f.create_dataset(f'frame_{pid:04}_{nfr:03}',data=arr)
 
with h5py.File('SO_67702838.h5','r') as h5f:       
    subject_counts = {}   
    for ds_name in h5f.keys():
        subject = ds_name[6:10]
           
        if subject not in subject_counts:
            count = 1
        else:
            count += 1
        subject_counts[subject]=count
            
print(subject_counts)            
arr0 = np.array(list(subject_counts.items()))
print(arr0)
arr1 = np.array(list(subject_counts.keys()))
print(arr1)
arr2 = np.array(list(subject_counts.values()))
print(arr2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a legend

Comment: A `defaultdict` might make the code a bit simpler.